# Google MVP в картах

Tags: java, android

Я хочу использовать MVP и карту. Для первого запуска работает все идеально, но когда я вращаю телефон получаю `NullExeption` в `addMarkersOnMap` потому что GoogleMap еще не создался.

Объясните пожалуйста логику, как правильно нужно работать с такими приложениями когда кроме Rx есть еще и CallBack. Я понимаю что мой код не правильный. Поэтому и ожидаю в свой адрес критику, но с объяснением. Заранее спасибо.

```
  public class MainActivity extends MvpAppCompatActivity implements IMain, OnMapReadyCallback {
    @InjectPresenter MainPresenter presenter;
    @BindView(R.id.frameProgress) FrameLayout frameProgress;
    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void showProgress() {
        frameProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void hideProgress() {
        frameProgress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        this.googleMap=googleMap;
    }

    @Override
    public void addMarkersOnMap(Place place) {
        for (Place.DataItem item: place.getData()) {
            LatLng latLng=new LatLng(item.getLat(),item.getLng());
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng));
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
    @InjectViewState
public class MainPresenter extends MvpPresenter<IMain> {

    @Override
    protected void onFirstViewAttach() {
        super.onFirstViewAttach();
        getViewState().showProgress();

        ApiRequest.getPlace()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .doOnTerminate(() -> getViewState().hideProgress())
                .subscribe(place -> {
                    getViewState().addMarkersOnMap(place);
                },throwable -> {
                    Log.e("MainPresenter=onFirstViewAttach", throwable.getMessage() + "");
                });
    }
}
```

---

[image: StackTrace]

Answer (score 1):

ну тут всё просто, всё что касается карты должно иниться только после того как отработает `onMapReady()` т.е. ваш запрос к апи желательно вызывать после коллбека. т.е. вы выносите запрос в отдельный метод и вызываете его из активити в коллбеке.

Будет так:

```
 @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        this.googleMap=googleMap;
        presenter.getPlace();
    }
```

И потом в презентере (не забудьте в контракте метод объявить):

```
@Override
public void getPlace() {
 getViewState().showProgress();
 ApiRequest.getPlace()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .doOnTerminate(() -> getViewState().hideProgress())
                .subscribe(place -> {
                    getViewState().addMarkersOnMap(place);
                },throwable -> {
                    Log.e("MainPresenter=onFirstViewAttach", throwable.getMessage() + "");
                });
}
```

И рекомендации по использованию `RxJava`:
`getViewState().showProgress();` вызывайте непосредственно в цепочке Rx'a в методе `doOnSubscribe();`
и скрытие прогресса лучше в `doAfterTerminate()` или `doFinally()`
Эти методы вызываются после того, как отработал `subscribe()` как в случае успеха, так и в случае ошибки т.е. прогресс закроется после того как всё необходимое заатачится на вьюху или упадет ошибка.

И можно совсем довести до идеала - сам запрос к `Domain` слою (гуглу) скрыть от презентера и вынести в `Interactor` - класс прослойка между презентером и моделью, он берет данные из модели в "сыром" виде и отдает их прозентеру в нужном для него виде, презентер выполняет логические операции и вызывает вью. И если ещё красивее то используйте `UseCase`. В `Clean Architecture` это, если простыми словами, интерактор который отвечает только за один конкретный запрос к модели. К примеру вам от гугла надо два запроса. один даёт `Place` другой даёт `Polyline`. Это либо один `Interactor`, либо два `UseCase`. Ну если капнуть еще дальше - то работу с гуглом вам надо еще обернуть в паттерн `Repository`

Хорошие примеры всего этого : [Google blue prints GitHub repo](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture)

**And one more thing:**

У вас в методе вьюхи `addMarkersOnMap(Place place)` есть ненужная логика. проверки типов. доставание данных из объекта.

Помните, что ваша `View` должна быть максимально "тупой", поэтому логику доставания `LatLng` из `Place` выполняйте в `Presenter`'e а этот метод с маркером должен принимать уже готовые данные `addMarkersOnMap(LatLng place)` после чего от просто сетит координату в `MarkerOptions` и потом в карту. Вы можете возразить и сказать, почему бы `Presenter`'у сразу не передавать `MarkerOptions`. Ответ - `MarkerOptions` отвечает за визуальное отображение на карте и является частью `View`. К примеру вы месяц пишете на `Google Maps` а потом вдруг решите перейти на другие `OpenStreetMap` или `Here` к примеру. Так, вам придется менять только слой `View`. А если классы из пакета карты будут и в презентере, то вам и его придется переписывать. Хотя `LatLng` тоже конечно лежит в пакете гугл карт. Если уж совсем упороться в мои советы, то тогда презентер работать должен с двумя `long` переменными `(latitude & longtitude)` но это уже слишком и сугубо личное дело каждого насколько сильно упарываться в `MVP`) Поступайте как вам удобнее.

Главное - общие принципы:

1 - `View` максимально тупая.

2 - `Presenter` выполняет логические операции.

3 - `Interactor/UseCases` достают презентеру данные из слоя данных

4 - Слой данных (сеть/локальная БД/ префы/ Хранилище телефона) Я пользуюсь паттерном `Repository` из примеров гугла, что я кинул выше

Comment: Тут вы не правы. Ваш код не рабочий. Если перевернуть экран. То googleMap будет равен null pointer и автоматически вызовется `addMarkersOnMap`. В итоге Crash.....

Comment: где логика? addMarkersOnMap вызывается из метода презентера getPlace() этот метод вызывается в коллбеке onMapReady(). Тут физически null быть не может. Значит у вас где-то ошибка. я ж в своем проекте по такой структуре пишу, и всё отлично работает

Comment: Volkov, Незнаю. Вот исходники https://pastebin.com/ihgHpRE5.

Я получаю `NullPointerException` в `addMarkersOnMap`, на `googleMap`.

Поэтому и говорю что ваш способ не верный. А принимать ответ не хочу чтобы, других новичков таких же как я не бросить в заблуждение.

Comment: стектрейс докиньте в вопрос

Comment: Как видно в исходниках. По вашему способу нарушается вся система MVP. Зачем при повороте мне вызывать createPlace? Данный метод 1 раз должен работать.

Comment: Обновил вопрос. добавил `StackTrace`

Comment: Я говорил про метод с названием getPlace() а не createPlace(). веду к тому, что данный метод может кешировать данные и при повторном вызове отдавать из кеша. И как я вижу по стектрейсу, похоже, что данный метод addMarkers вызывается не из коллбека а при аттаче ваших IMain.State. что явно происходит раньше чем карта подгружается.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71723/discussion-between-eranewgames-and-sviat-volkov).

Comment: метод getPlace и createPlace одинаковый. Просто я меняю названия)). Дак так и должно быть. MVP так и работает. Презентер кеширует при атаче.

Вот поэтому я и хотел узнать у вас. Как логику поменять с CallBack от Google вместе с MVP. Уже 4 день ответа не могу найти, ни в гугле ни в стеке

Comment: @SviatVolkov, Здравствуйте, Можете скинуть исходники как вы реализовали данный код. Так как из примера Автора я не могу реализовать его. Код не рабочий. Дайте пожалуйста ваш рабочий пример

Comment: @Andro код автора я не трогал, и глядя на стектрейс, метод addMarkers вызывается не только из описанного мной решения (коллбек - презентер - активити)  но и из другого места при пересоздании активити, что там в том коде я не знаю, автор не скинул. Свой код (моё приложение, где я делал аналогичную задачу) я скинуть не могу, т.к. проект в котором я работаю с гугл картами коммерческий