# Что будет если вызывать Listener каждый раз?

Tags: java, android

Есть 2 кнопки A и B, при нажатии на A.запускается некий b.OnClickListener.

Какие последствия могут быть при таком подходе? Утечки не заметил....

---

```
Button button=new Button(this);

        button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(googleMap -> {
                System.out.println("TEST");
            });
        });
```

---

**@pavlofff**, Вы наверное не поняли что я хочу узнать). Незнаю насчет GC. Но я сейчас изучаю MVP и столкнулся с проблемой при использовании Google Maps. в SO нашел тему подобно моей задаче [GoogleMap MVP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/769951/google-mvp-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%85). Решил попробовать код. Код рабочий, но не понятно как работает. При повороте экрана. Выдает ошибку `NullPointer` в `addMarkersOnMap`.

Я решил эту проблему и перенес `mapFragment.getMapAsync(googleMap ->` в `addMarkersOnMap`. При повороте все работает хорошо и ничего не вызывается. Лишь данные добавляются в карту.

Метод `addMarkersOnMap` вызывается несколько раз. Может и 10 раз вызываться с интервалом в 2 сек к примеру. Поэтому и хочу узнать вообще правильно ли так делать. Если нет, то какой альтернативный способ найти, для решения моей задачи.

Comment: Покажите пример.

Comment: @post_zeew, добавил пример

Comment: Лучше всего, на время асинхронного действия, блокировать кнопку. Как минимум, это хорошо с точки зрения UI/UX.

Comment: однажды назначенный слушатель будет "действовать" до уничтожения объекта, который он "слушает", поэтому назначать несколько раз нет никакого смысла. При повторном назначении будет просто выполнена бесполезная операция. Объекты, которые были созданы при предыдущем назначении, скорее всего потеряют ссылки на объект прослушивания и будут уничтожены GC при удобном случае. Все это создаст дополнительную нагрузку на систему и больше ничего.

Comment: вы можете назначить слушатель один раз, при инициализации кнопки, а если от нажатия на нее требуются динамические действия, то из слушателя вызывать метод, который и будет "разруливать" динамику.

Comment: @pavlofff, Обновил вопрос, чтобы стало понятнее задача которую я хочу решить. `P.S. Незнаю правильно ли так делать или лучше создать новую тему и там обсудить...`

Answer (score 2):

Очевидно, нажатие будет обрабатываться каждый раз. Последствием этого может быть работающая кнопка.